# Return dict of most common values from a list of tuples of a edge network, allowing for ties

Tags: python

I need to transform a list of thousands of tuples that looks essentially like this:

`[('2975', '6384'), ('2975', '530'), ('7443', '1107983'), ('3534', '530')]`

Into a dict where the most common entry is returned along with a count for its frequency. The function also needs to allow for ties when more than one value is the maximum and report both.

So in the above scenario, I would get back:

`{'2975': 2, '530': 2}`

My current implementation

```
from collections import Counter

nodes = [('2975', '6384'), ('2975', '530'), ('7443', '1107983'), ('3534', '530')]

highest_nodes = {}

# converting nodes
data = Counter(list(sum(nodes, ()))).most_common()
val = data[0][1]  # get the value of n-1th item
for a, b in list(takewhile(lambda x: x[1] >= val, data)):
    highest_nodes.setdefault(a, []).append(b)
# This is returning values as a list containing the item, need to extract the int from it
return highest_nodes
```

Any ideas how I can get this done?

Thank you!

Comment: Pandas is probably the way to go with this.

Comment: Do you want it separated by where in the tuple it lies (index 0 or 1) or should all values be put into a single pool ?

Comment: What is the issue with your current solution?

Comment: @jab - This wont work, itll show you the top 2 occurrences regardless if they tie.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `dict()` then iterate it to get `max` value of `data` dict:

```
from collections import Counter

nodes = [('2975', '6384'), ('2975', '530'), ('7443', '1107983'), ('3534', '530')]

highest_nodes = {}

# converting nodes
data = dict(Counter(list(sum(nodes, ()))).most_common())

for a, b in data.items():
    if b == max(data.values()):
        highest_nodes.setdefault(a, b)

# {'2975': 2, '530': 2}
```

Comment: This will just show the top two results... the Op wants the top result or all equal top results.

Comment: @tomgalpin Oh... I see. Top result or all equals top results. Edited! Hopes this edit does what Op wants.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import Counter

nodes = [('2975', '6384'), ('2975', '530'), ('7443', '1107983'), ('3534', '530')]

node_1 = Counter([i[0] for i in nodes]).most_common(1)[0]
node_2 = Counter([i[1] for i in nodes]).most_common(1)[0]

return {node_1[0]: node_1[1], node_2[0]: node_2[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face is that most_common will either show you X amount of entries or all of them, there is no way to show all top entries if they have the same amount of occurrences using that function alone.

Note: in my example ive used the variable "d" instead of "nodes"

The method below, flattens the list of tuples into a single list,

```
[item for sublist in d for item in sublist]
```

converts to a counter to find each occurrence and then to an ordered list in order of occurrences using most_common.

```
Counter(flattened list from above code]).most_common()
```

Finally it uses a slice to display all indices of the list which all have the top count of occurrences and converts back to a dict.

```
[:d.values().count(max(d.values()))]


top_hits = dict(top_hits)
```

The complete code:

```
from collections import Counter 
d = [('2975', '6384'), ('2975', '530'), ('7443', '1107983'), ('3534', '530')]
counter =   Counter([item for sublist in d for item in sublist])
top_hits = counter.most_common()[:counter.values().count(max(counter.values()))]
top_hits = dict(top_hits)
print(top_hits)
{'2975': 2, '530': 2}
```