# How to print the most frequent name (plurality)?

Tags: python

I'm writing a plurality program in Python, letting voters vote for candidates and printing out the winner (most frequent name). I've managed to input the number of voters and their votes, but I can't seem to print out the winner. (It keeps printing out the least frequent.) And if you find any other errors, please correct them.

NB: This is a cs50 project. It was asked to be done in C, but I wanted to try it in Python.

```
from collections import Counter
#max = 9
candidates = ["Bob", "Steve", "Ross"]
for key in range(len(candidates)):
    print(candidates[key], end = " ")

v = []
voters = int(input("\nNumber of voters: "))
for i in range(voters):
    votes = input("Vote: ").capitalize()
    v.append(votes)
print(v)

vote_count = Counter(v)
print(vote_count)

max_votes = max(vote_count.keys())
print(max_votes)
```

Comment: Do you want most common : print(vote_count.most_common(1))?

Comment: Assuming your inputs are the names of the candidates, you are taking the max of the names, when you call max on the .keys(). You probably want what @funnydman suggests

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Counter.most_common(1)` to get the name with the most votes and their total number of votes. The `1` specifies that you only want the single most common name.

```py
from collections import Counter

candidates = ["Bob", "Steve", "Ross"]

# Your user input would go here, I used a list for quick testing
votes = [
    "Ross",
    "Bob",
    "Steve",
    "Bob",
    "Bob",
    "Steve",
    "Steve",
    "Bob"
]

print(Counter(votes).most_common(1))
```

Output:

```py
[('Bob', 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

> `max()` on list or key of string will return the string with the
> highest value, ordered alphabetically.

In your case, *Steve* is always printed. So if you have *Xavier* in candidates or input, it will always printed *Xavier* using `max(vote_count.key())` or `max(vote_count)` function.

To print most frequent name from `vote_count` you can use `max` with function list `count` as key:

```
max_votes = max(vote_count, key=v.count)
print(max_votes)
```

or get most frequent name from list `v`:

```
max_votes = max(v, key=v.count)
print(max_votes)
```

You also can iterate over the `vote_count` dict:

```
for candidate, voted in vote_count.items():
    if voted == max(vote_count.values()):
        max_votes = candidate
print(max_votes)
```

Or slicing `most.common()` index:

```
max_votes = vote_count.most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Comment: But what if there are two or more winners like a tie(an equal number of votes), how do I print all the winners?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73695500/19574157